# How to merge rows with duplicated values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select and merge rows that have the same values of two other columns (like a primary key in SQL). What functions should I use?

I've tried to use df.duplicate(subset=...), but it seems like not giving me a correct result.

For example, I want to merge rows that values of 'col B' and 'col D' are the same.

So this df would become

```
     col a   'col B'    col c   'col D'    col e
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 0     a       ABC-1     nan      ABCD      b,c
 1     a       ABC-2     nan      ABCD      aaa
 2     b       ABC-1      c       ABCD      b,c
 3     c       ABC-1     a,b      ABCD     b,c,d
 4     nan     ABC-3      c       AACE      b,c
```

this

```
      col a   'col B'    col c   'col D'    col e
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 0     a,c     ABC-1    a,b,c     ABCD      b,c,d
 1      a      ABC-2     nan      ABCD      aaa
 2     nan     ABC-3      c       AACE      b,c
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If order is not important split values without `NaN`s, convert to sets and `join` in custom function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
def f(x):
    out = set([z for y in x.dropna() for z in y.split(',')])
    return ','.join(out) if bool(out) else np.nan

df = df.groupby(['col B','col D']).agg(f).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   col a  col B  col c col D  col e
0  c,a,b  ABC-1  a,c,b  ABCD  c,b,d
1      a  ABC-2    NaN  ABCD    aaa
2    NaN  ABC-3      c  AACE    c,b
```

If order is important use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def f(x):
    out = OrderedDict.fromkeys([z for y in x.dropna() for z in y.split(',')]).keys()
    return ','.join(out) if bool(out) else np.nan

df = df.groupby(['col B','col D']).agg(f).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   col a  col B  col c col D  col e
0  a,b,c  ABC-1  c,a,b  ABCD  b,c,d
1      a  ABC-2    NaN  ABCD    aaa
2    NaN  ABC-3      c  AACE    b,c
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but my df has 'timestamp' column which causes an error :  'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'.
I guess for timestamp, there should be one value of the recent one(maybe update?).

Comment: @JeongPaul - Is possible set column to strings and apply this solution by `df['dates'] = df['dates'].astype(str)` if no missing values in this column`?

Comment: I dealt with timestamp thanks to your comment, but I keep getting attribute error. Since the df has over 100 columns, is there any way to fix Attribute Error for every column? Should I change all of their dtype?

Comment: @JeongPaul - Then use `df = df.astype(str).mask(df.isna())`

Comment: @JeongPaul - Or `df = df.where(df.isna(), df.astype(str))` - because if use only `df = df.astype(str)` then NaNs are converted to strings nans

Comment: @JeongPaul - Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look the below solution.

```
groups = df.groupby(['b','d'])

def reduce_values(dataframe):
    vals = []
#     print(dataframe.columns)
    for i in dataframe.columns:
        if dataframe[i].dropna().count():
            vals.append(','.join(set(dataframe[i].dropna().str.split(',').sum())))
        else:
            vals.append(dataframe[i][dataframe[i].index[-1]])
    return vals


# ndf

ndf = groups.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([reduce_values(x)],columns=[i for i in x.columns if i not in groups.size().index.names])).reset_index(level=2,drop=True)

print(ndf)
```